# Why is my TFS build activity not being rendered in the XAML viewer after upgrade to VS 2015?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, nunit

- We're trying to upgrade from TFS 2010 to TFS 2015.
- We've got NUnit tests for which we were using a TFS build activity called TfsBuildExtensions.Activities.CodeQuality.NUnit.
- The TFS build activity is not being rendered and I'm getting the following error:

> Could not find type 'TfsBuildExtensions.Activities.CodeQuality.NUnit'
>   in assembly 'TfsBuildExtensions.Activities'

[image: screenshot of XAML]

Does anyone know why this would be happening and how to get around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process template is different in TFS 2010 and TFS 2015. Please check whether you have used the new version of the Activities from website https://github.com/tfsbuildextensions/CustomActivities.

**NOTE**: In VS/TFS 2012 + unit testing is based on an extensible system, it is no longer limited to only supporting MSTest as in previous versions of Visual Studio. If the nUnit adapter is downloaded from Visual Studio Gallery then nUnit tests can be included within a solution and build without the need for this custom activity. https://github.com/tfsbuildextensions/CustomActivities/wiki/Getting%20started%20with%20the%20nUnit%20activity

> Using the new test adapters should be the preferred option instead of
>   this activity.

Additionally, since you have upgraded to TFS 2015, it's suggested to use new build system which is tasks based. You can run Tests using [Visual Studio Test](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/VsTest/README.md) task, and specify the path to Custom Test Adaptors in the task to use NUnit test framework.

Comment: Thanks...this helped....Primarily, this link from the site you've linked: https://github.com/tfsbuildextensions/CustomActivities/wiki/Integrate%20Build%20Activities